# Regular Expression allows specific special characters in java

Tags: java, android, regex

I need to know the regular expression for string that contains alphanumeric characters, @, underscore(_), full stop(.)and not any blank spaces. And also for alphanumeric characters and it allow spaces. I tried with this regex,

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\.\\@]$ and ^[A-Za-z0-9-\\s]$
```

**CODE:**

```
private static final String Username_REGEX ="^[_A-Za-z0-9.@-]$";

public static boolean isUsername(EditText editText, boolean required) {
    return isValid(editText, Username_REGEX,Username_MSG, required);
}


public static boolean isValid(EditText editText, String regex, String errMsg, boolean required) {
    String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();

    editText.setError(null);

  if ( required && !hasTextemt(editText) ) return false;

    if (required && !Pattern.matches(regex, text)) {
        editText.setError(errMsg);
        return false;
    };

    return true;
}

public static boolean hasTextemt(EditText editText) {

    String text = editText.getText().toString().trim();
    editText.setError(null);


    if (text.length() == 0) {
        editText.setError(emt);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is this correct? I did not get proper result. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: are you trying for email address verification?

Comment: @DigveshPatel yeah ofcourse

Comment: @SMR yeah i tried and it works fine

Comment: You forgot to include your `isValid` method. You are forwarding its result so it is kind of important.

Comment: @Pshemo I pasted the isvalid methos

Comment: `Pattern.matches(regex, text)` checks if entire text matches regex, not if it contains part that matches regex. Also your current regex will match only one character. To solve this problem add `+` after `[...]` part so it will have to match **one or more** of characters described in `[]`. With that you will not have to check if your string is empty using `hasTextemt(editText)`.

Answer (score 3):

Move the dash `-` at the end of the character class:

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9.@-]+$
```

and

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\\s-]+$
```

Between two characters it means a range.

*Edit:* You also need a `+` modifier to match one or more of the characters in the character class.

Comment: I place ur regex in my regex variable and evaluate with my input it shows invalid text

Comment: @Barbie: Please, edit your question and add the code you're using.

Comment: @Barbie/ I see, you have to add a `+` modifier at the end of the regex. This means that it'll match one or more characters within the character class.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are getting this input via an `EditText` widget. So inside the layout of the `XML` file you can add the following properties by which it will receive only specified characters. :

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,.-@_"
```

note that it wont allow any capital letter.

just add any digits/keys you want your user to be able to enter. If you are **not** worried about the **patterns** and **number of occurrence** of any character then you don't even need any **regex**.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
"[\\w@\\.]+" //for alphanumeric, @, .

"[\\w\\s]+" //for alphanumeric, spaces
```

Add ^ and $ if you need that matches the whole word.

PS: For testing regexp I always use [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) (not spam :P)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are only missing a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). In your expression `^[_A-Za-z0-9.@-]$`, the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[_A-Za-z0-9.@-]` matches exactly one character out of the class. To allow repeated characters, you need to define a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

`*` short for `{0,}` matches 0 or more characters (==> this allows the empty string!)

`+` short for `{1,}` matches 1 or more characters

`{n,m}` matches minimum `n` and maximum `m` characters.

So your regex would look like

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9.@-]+$
```

if you require 1 or more characters, or

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9.@-]{6,20}$
```

if you want at least 6 characters and at most 20.

**Other things:**

- You can replace `_A-Za-z0-9` by `\w`, but be aware, `\w` is Unicode based and contains all letters and digits from all languages.
- `A-Za-z` is only ASCII, maybe you want to have a look at [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop). With e.g. `\p{L}` you can match a letter of any language.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a plus sign (meaning one or more) at the end of the character class, *and* you can simplify considerably:

```
^[\\w.@]+$
```

Characters within a character class lose their special meanings so don't need to be escaped, except for square brackets and a couple of others.

---

For alphanumeric and spaces only, that is only combinations of letters, numbers and spaces:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

Comment: how can i design a regex that only allows alphanumeric characters and spaces